# Django serves zero byte response

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

This just happened to one of my sites and I have no idea what caused it.
This happens for any URL that is served by mod_wsgi for a particular application, which used to work fine.

[image]

Syntax errors in `settings.py` cause HTTP 500.
Syntax errors in `urls.py` don't influence anything—seems like this file is never loaded.

What is there to check?

Comment: Did you try running you app using the dev server to see if all settings are OK and if there are any errors show up? (Of course, don't do that on port 80).

Comment: @Thomas, it says 0 errors found.

Comment: Your webserver appears to be Apache, did you check the error.log file?

Comment: Yes, I did. No errors in the logs, just nothing.

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Apache will only reload these files when it is restarted, whereas the dev server would monitor them for changes.

Comment: @Tony, by now I probably restarted it about a hundred times :-).

Comment: @Thomas, I found the solution—I wonder if you can shed some light on why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was this line:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
```

in `middleware.py`.

Moving the import into the function that uses `AuthenticationForm` solved the problem:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm <-- THE LINE WAS HERE

class LoginFormMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'is_top_login_form' in request.POST:
            from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm # <-- MOVED HERE

            form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
            is_valid = form.is_valid()

            if is_valid:
                login(request, form.get_user())

                program = request.user.get_profile().first_intern.program
                NavigationMiddleware.set_program(request, program)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?quick' % program.get_absolute_url())

            else:
                messages.error(request, request.POST['username'], extra_tags='login')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
```

I still have no idea why the code used to work, why it suddenly broke and why doing this solved the problem.
There has to be some magick in Python, after all.

Comment: Were any changes made in settings.py in relation to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings?  A django file shouldn't be the culprit.  The middleware classes are very picky about the order.  Was this modified at all?

Comment: No, I didn't change the order of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, or for that matter, did not change `settings.py`. I'm able to reproduce the problem by removing the comment on that import.